# Delete the euro-sign (€) keyboard-shortcut (AltGr + E) via remapping the registry in windows

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry, remapping

I'm trying to delete the <kbd>AltGR</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> shortcut for making a euro-sign `€` via remapping in the registry in Windows.

I have found out that remapping in the registry is possible by searching some [Stack overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1441821/2489106) and found out that there is a Windows topic about the [same issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463447.aspx). But I do not have the skills to code it myself :(

Has anybody tried something like this? or have a solution for doing this in the registry?

I'm on a Danish qwerty-keyboard on Windows 7. <kbd>AltGR</kbd> is the right alt-key on a danish keyboard.

---

**Edit 19/07/13:**

This is the `KBDDA.dll` file on my computer in the windows/system32-folder. It controls my Danish keyboard layout.

It has the following code:

[image]

What do I delete/change to get the <kbd>AltGR</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> shortcut to disappear?

Answer (score 0):

You should check this guide:

**Remapping the Keyboard Layout in Windows XP, Vista, and 7**

http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/remap-keyboard.htm

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have yet to find a way to do this manually, so if anyone have the answer please reply!

Comment: The links looks dead

Comment: @raffamaiden use archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20170813060317/http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/remap-keyboard.htm

Answer (score 0):

(on hindsight, you can only change combination keys aka shortcuts via AutoHotKey software. But if you want to delete the AltGr key, do this:)

Always back up your registry via the **File|Export** command 
create a text file and call it *DisableAltKey.reg* and paste this into it:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Delete Right Alt Key"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,09,00,00,00,00,00,e0,38,00,00,00,00

Save it on your desktop, double click it, reboot and the AltGr key will do nothing.

The basis for this method I found here, they make it clear with pictures and colours. 
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/

Comment: Didn't work nor for Ctrl+Alt+E nor for AltGr+E. I still get the euro sign in both cases